# VBA excel - using a variable to select a column range

Tags: excel, vba

VBA - The user selects a number from a combobox (1-50) and it is assigned as a variable. I now want to program a function which selects columns BA to a column to the left whatever value the user selected (I.E. from AV:BA where AV is the variable column). I have the variable the user slects as a string (dim var as string). Your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The OFFSET property is what you're looking for, although to give you a full answer it would be helpful if you posted the code you've written thus far.

Here is some more info about how OFFSET works:

http://www.excel-vba.com/vba-code-2-6-cells-ranges.htm

**Edit:** Here is a quick and dirty example to get you going.  In this case, the SelectColumns subroutine takes a single parameter which tells it how many columns to the left of BA should be selected (along with BA).  If you execute the Test subroutine, you'll see that columns AY:BA get selected on the active worksheet.

```
Sub SelectColumns(numColsToLeft As Integer)
    Range(Range("BA1").EntireColumn, Range("BA1").Offset(0, -numColsToLeft).EntireColumn).Select
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Call SelectColumns(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: yes but then do i put in the variable in the offset? 
    Columns("-str:BA").Select
str is my variable

Comment: Public Sub SampleBox_Change()
Dim str As Integer
If (SampleBox.ListIndex > -1) Then
    str = SampleBox.List(SampleBox.ListIndex)
End If

End Sub

Public Sub Samplesdel(str As Integer)
Range(Range("BA1").EntireColumn, Range("BA1").Offset(0, -str).EntireColumn).Select
End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.Run "Samplesdel"



End Sub